# C++ : Value passed through function parameters is giving different result

Tags: c++, double

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I'm writing a mortgage calculator and I'm breaking it down step by step since the first outcome didn't work. However, I'm having an issue initializing the function with the value 250000. If I run it, it ends up giving me 12500 versus 1250 which is the correct answer.

I added cout << 250000 * monthlyRate << endl; to check if there was an issue here, but this displays correctly as well if I enter it through cout before the function in main and it works fine too. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double mortgageCalculator(double principal, double rate, double years);

int main()
{

    // local variables
    double principal, rate, years;

    cout << "How much is the principal amount" << endl;
    cin >> principal;
    // cout << "What is the yearly rate?" << endl;
    // cin >> rate;
    // cout << "Term of mortgage (years) " << endl;
    // cin >> years;

    cout << mortgageCalculator(25000, 6, 30) << endl;

    return 0;
}

double mortgageCalculator(double principal, double rate, double years)
{
    rate = rate / 100.0;
    cout << rate << endl;

     double result, monthlyRate = rate / 12.0;
    cout << monthlyRate << endl;

    result = principal * monthlyRate;
    cout << 250000 * monthlyRate << endl;
    cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're printing out what the function returns:

```
cout << mortgageCalculator(25000, 6, 30) << endl;
```

And in the function you have:

```
return 0;
```

So you'll print out the correct result (1250) and then add on a 0. It looks like you just want to return the result instead of printing it out in the function.

```
return principal * monthlyRate;
```

And remove all the prints inside the function.

Comment: That was a quick reply, now re-reading my code I'm seeing what you mean. I changed it to return result for the equation and it's working as expected.    result = (principal * monthlyRate) / (1 - (1 / pow((1 + monthlyRate), (years *12))));